# Test class for queueable apex trigger handler with http callout

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock

Whenever a new record of object abc is created, a queueable trigger handler  makes http callout. My trigger handler is working fine and i am able to do what I intended, but when I test this trigger handler, I get this error -

"System.TypeException: Mock object doesn't implement the supplied interface"

Please provide some insights on what I am doing wrong and how to correct it. Thanks.

this is my mock response generator-

```
@isTest
global class MockFirebaseResponseGenerator {
    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setBody('{"success":1,"failure":0}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    }
}

@isTest
public class TEST_FirebaseNotificationHandler {
    @isTest 
    static void testCallout(){
        // create test data
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockFirebaseResponseGenerator());       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific error is a simple omission of the implementation of HttpCalloutMock. Change:

```
global class MockFirebaseResponseGenerator
```

To:

```
global class MockFirebaseResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock
```

Note, too, that it is unlikely you need to make any of what you have here `global` and should instead use `public`. The `global` access modifier is for cross-namespace access.